# Can't convert app bundle to NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdata

I'm trying to convert my bundle to NSData so that I can hash the data and have a server verify the hash before allowing downloads. The only problem is that when I try to convert the bundle to NSData, I get `Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)` I looked up error 257 and it means that the bundle couldn't be read due to a permissions problem. What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks for your help.

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];  
NSLog(@"%@", bundlePath);
NSError *error;
NSData *bData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath options:nil error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can read your bundle... only its content. The bundle is probably located one folder higher up than you are allowed to read.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist What would you recommend to read and hash otherwise? I want to ensure that the app has not been changed in any way before allowing it to download things.

Comment: You are thinking of anti-piracy measures? Otherwise the OS should make sure that the app stays intact.

Comment: Yes, I also want to use the hash to log into my server to download things... it ensures that the app has not been messed with and that only users of the app can download the content.

Comment: Why don't you do that with the binary instead of the complete bundle?

Comment: A bundle is not a single file, it's a, well, bundle. It makes no sense to imagine a single `NSData` holding the contents of a bundle. Also, even if it did, surely you'd want to read it piecemeal instead of loading the whole thing into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If piracy protection is your ultimate goal, refer to this for a little insight and code.

http://thwart-ipa-cracks.blogspot.com/2008/11/detection.html?m=1